# Can not connect nodeJs version 19 to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem connecting my nodejs app to mongoDB driver. I have nodejs v19.6.0 working on my windows 10. I have tried connecting my app to mongo compass but no connection is working. I read on mongodb docs about the change in DNS resolution and the changes that happened since v18. I have tried to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 in the url, and also set ipv6 = true in the mongodb config file but nothing is working. Kindly can someone help me resolve this. I'm frustrated since it's a week without finding a workable solution on the internet.[screenshot of the error. nodemon is stack on starting my index.js file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iNmB.png)

I tried changing the url ip address from var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb"; to var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb";

I also added the config file the net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 127.0.0.1
ipv6: true
bindIpAll: true

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551